# django multiple sites wsgi is enough?

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, wsgi

I intend to have many python with django applications on my server,

is it ok to have django with wsgi and many sites on the one server?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can have as many different django sites as your server can handle!  You can set up separate virtual hosts pointing to the appropriate wsgi for each site you want.

Remember just because it is possible doesn't mean it's a good idea, keep in mind the resources each site is consuming.